# PHP: File upload not working properly

Tags: html, php

Hi I'm new to PHP(I'm an asp.net developer) and just switched to PHP because I needed to develop a website for my friend.  I am currently trying to upload music files into a folder on my website but keeps on getting this error:

> Notice: "Undefined index: uploadedfile in C:\xampp\htdocs\sitename\admin\uploader.php on line 5"

I've tried following steps:

1. Set the max_upload_filesize and post_max_size to "1028M".
2. Added "enctype="multipart/form-data" to my form tag.
3. Tried "print_r($_FILES);" and the array keeps on returning empty.
4. Used the upload script in a new website and it works fine.
5. Tried so many different scripts online but none worked and finally i tried this but still facing the same problem.

Here is my code below:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <title>ControlHome</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/admin.css">
    <script src="../js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/superfish.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/tms-0.4.1.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/slider.js"></script>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
   <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
     <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode">
       <img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today." />
    </a>
  </div>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="../js/html5.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css"> 
<![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="main-bg">

                         <div class="page">
                         <form method="GET" action="uploader.php" enctype="multipart/form-data> 
                           <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                             <tr>
                               <td>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
    <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</td>
                               <td>&nbsp;</td>
                               <td>&nbsp;</td>
                               <td>&nbsp;</td>
                             </tr>
                           </table>
</form>
                         </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
    </footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

PHP

```
<?php
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '1028M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '1028M');

echo $_FILES['uploadedfile']['error'];
print_r($_FILES);

//**********************************************************************************************


echo "Please wait while we attempt to upload your file...<br><br>";

//**********************************************************************************************


$target_path = "uploads/";

$flag = 0; // Safety net, if this gets to 1 at any point in the process, we don't upload.

$filename = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];
$filesize = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['size'];
$mimetype = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['type'];

$filename = htmlentities($filename);
$filesize = htmlentities($filesize);
$mimetype = htmlentities($mimetype);

$target_path = $target_path . basename( $filename );

if($filename != ""){

echo "Beginning upload process for file named: ".$filename."<br>";
echo "Filesize: ".$filesize."<br>";
echo "Type: ".$mimetype."<br><br>";

}

//First generate a MD5 hash of what the new file name will be
//Force a MP3 extention on the file we are uploading

$hashedfilename = md5($filename);
$hashedfilename = $hashedfilename.".mp3";

//Check for empty file
if($filename == ""){
$error = "No File Exists!";
$flag = $flag + 1;

}

//Now we check that the file doesn't already exist.
$existname = "uploads/".$hashedfilename;

if(file_exists($existname)){

if($flag == 0){
$error = "Your file already exists on the server!  
Please choose another file to upload or rename the file on your
computer and try uploading it again!";
}

$flag = $flag + 1;
}

//Whitelisted files - Only allow files with MP3 extention onto server...

$whitelist = array(".mp3");
foreach ($whitelist as $ending) {

if(substr($filename, -(strlen($ending))) != $ending) {
 $error = "The file type or extention you are trying to upload is not allowed!  
You can only upload MP3 files to the server!";
$flag++;
}
}


//Now we check the filesize.  If it is too big or too small then we reject it
//MP3 files should be at least 1MB and no more than 6.5 MB

if($filesize > 6920600){
//File is too large

if($flag == 0){
$error = "The file you are trying to upload is too large!  
Your file can be up to 6.5 MB in size only.  
Please upload a smaller MP3 file or encode your file with a lower bitrate.";
}

$flag = $flag + 1;
}

if($filesize < 1048600){
//File is too small

if($flag == 0){
$error = "The file you are trying to upload is too small!
Your file has been marked as suspicious because our system has
determined that it is too small to be a valid MP3 file.
Valid MP3 files must be bigger than 1 MB and smaller than 6.5 MB.";
}

$flag = $flag + 1;

}

//Check the mimetype of the file
if($mimetype != "audio/x-mp3" and $mimetype != "audio/mpeg"){

if($flag == 0){
$error = "The file you are trying to upload does not contain expected data.
Are you sure that the file is an MP3?";
}

$flag = $flag + 1;
}

//Check that the file really is an MP3 file by reading the first few characters of the file
$f = @fopen($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'],'r');
$s = @fread($f,3);
@fclose($f);
if($s != "ID3"){

if($flag == 0){
$error = "The file you are attempting to upload does not appear to be a valid MP3 file.";
}

$flag++;
}



//All checks are done, actually move the file...

if($flag == 0){

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {


    //Change the filename to MD5 hash and FORCE a MP3 extention.

    if(@file_exists("uploads/".$filename)){

    //Rename the file to an MD5 version
    rename("uploads/".$filename, "uploads/".$hashedfilename);

    echo "The file ".  basename( $filename ). "
     has been uploaded.  Your file is <a href='uploads/$hashedfilename'>here</a>.";

    }  
    else{
      echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }


} else{
    echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
}

}
else {
echo "File Upload Failed!<br>";
if($error != ""){
echo $error;
}
} 
?>
```

Comment: Is the html code and php code in the same file?

Comment: Can you show us uploader.php - what happens on line 5?

Comment: The html and php codes are in serperate files.

Comment: Notice: Undefined index: uploadedfile in C:\xampp\htdocs\dopeTunezGH\admin\uploader.php on line 19

Notice: Undefined index: uploadedfile in C:\xampp\htdocs\dopeTunezGH\admin\uploader.php on line 20
Notice: Undefined index: uploadedfile in C:\xampp\htdocs\dopeTunezGH\admin\uploader.php on line 21
File Upload Failed!

Comment: 19   -    $filename = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'];
20   -    $filesize = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['size'];
21   -    $mimetype = $_FILES['uploadedfile']['type'];

Comment: Sorry i was doing some debugging and commented out the code the errors are actually on line 19, 20 and 21 not line 5.

Comment: FYI: `ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '1028M');` is ***useless***.

Comment: FYI: `ini_set('post_max_size', '1028M');` is ***useless***.

Comment: Hint: You can not set all ini directives with the `ini_set()`. Consult the PHP documentation where you can set those settings (in case you need some day): http://www.php.net/ini.core.php#ini.sect.data-handling / http://www.php.net/configuration.changes.modes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
 <head>
  <title>ControlHome</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/admin.css">
  <script src="../js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/superfish.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/tms-0.4.1.js"></script>
  <script src="../js/slider.js"></script>
  <!--[if lt IE 8]>
   <div style=' clear: both; text-align:center; position: relative;'>
     <a href="http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/internet-explorer/products/ie/home?ocid=ie6_countdown_bannercode">
      <img src="http://storage.ie6countdown.com/assets/100/images/banners/warning_bar_0000_us.jpg" border="0" height="42" width="820" alt="You are using an outdated browser. For a faster, safer browsing experience, upgrade for free today." />
     </a>
  </div>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="../js/html5.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css"> 
 <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div class="main-bg">
<div class="page">
 <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="uploader.php" method="POST">
     <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
         <tr>
           <td>
              <!-- MAX_FILE_SIZE must precede the file input field -->
            Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
            </td>
         </tr>
     </table>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You just need to remove extra form tag and use POST as method.

Comment: Weird, it didn't work the first time i did that but now it does thanx alot. :D

Comment: I probably forgot to take out the extra form tag before.

Comment: So it's working fine?? If yes then U can mark it as answer. :)

Comment: Well this was the same answer as @vivek gave before, to be honest. Probably you did not clear the cache before trying again ;)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the closing Quiation marks (") on The first form en the enctype property the you open another form withour closing the first one, is not necesary to have two forms, you should delete the first opening form tag.

Comment: I tried that but i keep getting the same errors, no change.

Answer (score 0):

Change form method="GET"  ....  to form method="POST"  ....

Comment: It used to be " method="POST" " but that didn't work also that is why i changed it to " method="GET" but that also is not working".

Answer (score 0):

Check if the server can write files to the `tmp` direcotry. Set PHP temp path explicitly if needed.

Comment: I checked that, i tried it with a different site and i am able to write to the temp directory.

Comment: It's the same site settings for all sites, I guess... Does the actual file transfer start - is there any file added to the temp directory? There must be a difference to the other sites you tested with. Double check and compare configurations.